# Building a cubic polynomial with certain parameters

Tags: calculus, polynomials, derivatives, cubics

I am trying to build a cubic polynomial $y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ with the following conditions:

$y(0) = 3$

$y'(0) = 2$

$y'(1) = 0$

$y(1) = 4$

Unfortunately, solving the required system yields $a = 0$.  I am trying to understanding geometrically why this must be the case.  I want a local *max* at $(1,4)$ and the slope at the y-intercept to equal $2$.

This problem builds on a simpler problem of finding a quadratic that satisfies the first three conditions, which gives $y = -x^2 + 2x + 3$, thereby yielding the fourth.  Thus, I am looking for a different value of $b$ in the cubic, and I would like to compensate for it with $a$.

For the quadratic, we have $y'' = -2$.

For the cubic, we have $y'' = 6ax + 2b$.  I want $y'$ to also have a net change of $-2$ over the interval $[0,1]$, while $y$ has a net change of $+1$.

Can anyone explain why, due to growth rates, that this is not possible with a cubic, or if there's something I'm missing?

Update:

The general case of this same question:

$y'(\alpha) = 2$

$y'(\alpha+1) = 0$

$\displaystyle \int_{\alpha}^{\alpha + 1} y' dy = 1$

for a cubic $y$ yields $a = 0$.  As the average value of $y'$ is $1$, the only way to satisfy the third condition is if $y'$ is indeed linear.  Have I answered my own question, and should I be ashamed to be a Calculus teacher?

[image: area under y']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $n$ constraints of this type, one of which must be on $f$ and not $f'$ or any other derivative, you are guaranteed to create a single polynomial with order **at most** $n-1$.  Since solving these constraints is solving a system of linear equations, there is no practical restraint on getting 0s for the highest-order coefficients.

For a more extreme instance, obviously the constraints $f(0)=2$, $f'(0)=f'(1)=f'(50)=3$, you're only ever going to get $f(x)=3x+2$, a linear function, despite the four inputs.

Comment: I understand that - what I mean is something due to curvature here.  For example, in my conditions, $y(1) = 5$ would be impossible as a local max because the polynomial is concave down.  I should however be able to obtain a local max anywhere below $(1,5)$ with a quadratic, and I thought I could somehow control cubic growth to do the same thing.

Comment: You got lucky.  Try a different target maximum.

Comment: More completely: in your case, you have $8x^3-13x^2+2x+3-2ax^3+3ax^2$, where $a$ is your chosen maximum at $x=1$.  $a=4$ is the only one that will actually manage to set your cubic coefficient to $0$.

Comment: Forgive me, but where are you getting this equation?

Comment: That's $y(0)=3$, $y'(0)=2$, $y'(1)=0$, $y(1)=a$.  I then built the equations, solved the system and got that.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I am still upset about all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct -
it is a cubic with 
the coefficient of 
$x^3$ being zero.

Believe.

Comment: I know, but *why* it is impossible to build it with a nonzero coefficient, arithmetic aside?  I thought one could tailor a polynomial (no pun intended) to satisfy any suitable conditions.  What is it about my conditions that prevent a nonzero leading coefficient?

Comment: That is just the way it turns out. Unexpected, but that's life.